# Is it possible to add the VM to a specified AD by default in vRealize Automation?

Tags: active-directory, vmware, vsphere

Is it possible to make a configuration file that adds a VM to the specified AD (domain) in the time of its creation in vRealize?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year old. But the easiest way to do this is to create a Customization Specification within v Center.

[image]

Once this is created inside your Blueprint within VRA, go to Build Information and within Customization Spec: enter in your newly created Customization Specification.
Once the machine is created it will join your Windows Domain.

[image]

If This is a Linux Machine, the best thing that i found was to install all the required setup files within the template, create a Shell Script with the Join Realm Command. Create a Software Component within vRA with Actions Install:

```
cd /etc/bin
sudo ./join.sh
```

Configure:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/bin
```

Inside your RedHat or Linux Blueprint Drag over your Join Domain Software Component.

[image]

Comment: Cool. Thanks Dave. Let me try this.

Comment: Did this help out?